# VB.NET run BATCH from current directory

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I have a windows `batch file` which I want to execute using vb.net however the batch as well as the VB.net exe that will execute it are run from the `cd rom` which means tat i want my vb.net to run the batch from `current directory` (as both will be placed in the current directory, on CD)

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an instance of [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfbyhds5.aspx) class, set the property `WorkingDir` and `FileName` (eventually also the `Arguments` property) and pass this instance to the `Start` static method or the [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

```
Dim pi = new ProcessStartInfo()
pi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
pi.FileName = "your_batch_file_name"
pi.Arguments = "arguments that you want to pass to the batch file"
Process.Start(pi)
```

Keep in mind that if you run from a CD then your current working directory is not writeable